# Upload image to host

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I ran into a problem I can upload a image to a directory on my server (not localhost) but it generates a file called: "array" but in the file browser is has the right visual. this is my code:

```
$ntitel = $_POST['titel'];
  $npost = $_POST['bericht'];
  $filetmp = $_FILES["file_image"]["temp_name"];
  $filename = $_FILES["file_image"]["name"];
  $filetype = $_FILES["file_image"]["type"];
  $filepath = "../daphne.db/images/nieuwsplaatjes/".$filename;

  move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filename);

  $ntitel = mysql_real_escape_string($ntitel);
  $npost = mysql_real_escape_string($npost);


  $query = "INSERT INTO nieuws (ntitel, npost, afb, afbtype, afbnaam) VALUES     ('$ntitel', '$npost', '$filepath', '$filetype', '$filename');";


  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h3>Je bericht is toegevoegt aan de Nieuws en Weetjes pagina!</h3>";


}
```

ofcourse my connection goes before this code but this is the important stuff i think.

Comment: Looks like `$_FILES["file_image"]["name"]` is an `array`?

Comment: THat's clear, but how can i change that so it is not an array and it will upload the right file?

Comment: It's not uploading the right file? I thought you said the image looks right; it's just naming it wrong?

Comment: Yes, its naming it wrong, and this way i can not echo it back to my website

Comment: Maybe useful information: its inserting the correct link in the database.

Comment: Well, since you are getting arrays for those values, it seems you have multiple file inputs. So you'll need to use an array indexer `[0]` at the end of them; `$filename = $_FILES["file_image"]["name"][0];`

Comment: Also; your code seems to be `move_uploaded_file` the file simply as `$filename`, and not `$filepath`

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
$filename = $_FILES["file_image"]["name"][0];
```

do the same for `size` and `type` also.

see a similar thread here:http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10333599-Upload-Image-Problem

Comment: So I have tried both of the solutions but when I use the array indexer like mentioned above, The file name and type appear to only have one letter in the database. Also I have changed the move_uploaded_file to    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath); not working though. I am not wanting to upload multiple files, just one single picture to include with the post.

Comment: just dump these values and see what they contain then you will have better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error, `temp_name` should be `tmp_name`